# Next parameter in CouchDB Session API?

Tags: forms, session, redirect, couchdb

In a Couchapp, I would like to have a login form that works without Javascript.

The [wiki page about the Session API](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Session_API) states that one can provide a next parameter to `_session` to be redirected after authentication success or failure.

This sounds great and I would like to redirect to a show function that can then check the user's credentials and display something accordingly.

I tried using a form:

```
<form action="/_session" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <input type="password" name="password">
  <input type="hidden" name="next" value="/somewhere">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

as well as using `curl`:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:5984/_session -d 'name=foo&password=bar&next=/somewhere'
```

but without success: I keep receiving code 200 (OK) if my credentials are correct and code 401 (Unauthorized) if they are not, but I never get the 302 (Redirection) that I expect.

Is this feature gone (I'm using Couchdb 1.1) or am I doing it the wrong way?

If this feature does not exist anymore, do you have an alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After browsing through the source code, it looks like the feature was implemented in v1.1.0.

See the [next parmeter implementation](https://github.com/apache/couchdb/blob/trunk/src/couchdb/couch_httpd_auth.erl#L282-286) in the CouchDB source code.

The parameter is only supported as a query string, not as a form field submission. Thus if you `POST` to `/_session?next=/somewhere` with the form data in the POST body, it will work.

```
curl -i https://example.iriscouch.com/_session?next=/stuff -d 'name=me&password=secret'
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Set-Cookie: AuthSession=[cookie value]; Version=1; Path=/; HttpOnly
Server: CouchDB/1.1.0 (Erlang OTP/R14B03)
Location: http://example.iriscouch.com/stuff
Date: Tue, 19 Jul 2011 01:07:52 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 52
Cache-Control: must-revalidate

{"ok":true,"name":"me","roles":["whoever"]}
```

Comment: I found the answer, I was just waiting to give people a chance to answer. Let's keep the suspens a little longer…

Comment: It kills me to yield to my arch nemesis; but since Simon was kind enough to wait, I added my own discovery to this one, to create a more comprensive answer.

Comment: Thanks Jason! For reference, I found this interesting [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-846) on the CouchDB bug tracker which would add a redirection on failure too.